# Changing the value of a list in a function through assignment

Tags: python, list, function

I understand that when we pass a list to a function in python, we actually pass an object reference to the list. Since a list is mutable, applying any list operations inside the function will actually cause changes to the list we're passing in.

Example:

```
def change_list(some_list):
    some_list.remove('old list')
    some_list.append('new list')

sample = ['old list']
print(sample) # prints ['old list']
change_list(sample) # print ['new list']
```

Of course, if we simply pass a copy of the list, there are no changes after calling `change_list(sample[:])`

Here is another scenario that will not cause the list to change:

```
def change_list(some_list):
    some_list = ['new list']

sample = ['old list']
change_list(sample)
print(sample) # still prints ['old list']
```

Ok, so this confuses me, since we're passing in the original list to the function and not a copy of the list, shouldn't python change the pointer of `sample` to now point to `['new list']` ?

What's more bizarre to me is that the following code will actually cause `sample` to point to `['new list']`

```
def change_list(some_list):
    some_list[:] = ['new list']

sample = ['old list']
change_list(sample)
print(sample) # now prints ['new list']
```

what's special about the `[:]` notation in the above code in terms of python's memory model. My speculation is that `some_list[:]` is a copy of the list we pass in but now `sample` points to the copy ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using `some_list = ['new list']` is just making `some_list` point to something else.  It does not change what is held at that memory location.  It does not effect what `some_list` used to refer to.  As for the `[:]`, when you say `some_list[:] = ...`, you are actually doing a shortcut for `some_list.__setitem__(slice(0, None), ...)`.  It is the same as setting `some_list[4]`, just on a larger scale.